# Why is JetBrains PyCharm markdown preview fuzzy with yellow artifacts under Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: pycharm, markdown, jetbrains-ide

On Ubuntu 18.04, on a 4k display with 200% screen scaling in Ubuntu, why does the Jetbrains PyCharm rendering of Markdown using the [built in markdown plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/markdown) display as fuzzy with yellow artifacts?

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm Markdown preview with a zoomed in section showing the problem]

This is a screenshot with an example of a section showing the problem zoomed in 2x so it's easier to see the issue.

Compare the display on the left of just native text in the IDE with the Markdown rendered preview on the right.

I've tried setting custom CSS in the IDE to see if that fixes anything but with no luck. I'd assumed that it related to my OS level scaling of 200% but when I try with not scaling, the same problem occurs (though it's a bit less noticeable as everything is really tiny).

This problem doesn't occur in JetBrains Intellij IDEA which also uses the "Markdown support" bundled plugin. In that case the content in the preivew pane looks crisp, the same as the native text in the IDE.

The problem occurs in JetBrains PyCharm 2019.1 using the "Markdown support" plugin which is bundled with PyCharm (as it's bundled it shows no version number in the Plugin settings page) on Ubuntu 18.04. It occurs in a brand new PyCharm settings profile (renamed settings folder, launched from scratch, installed Markdown plugin)

Comment: Perhaps a better question for SuperUser or Unix Stack Exchange. Unfortunately this is off-topic for Stack Overflow though.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Ah, I googled [which stackexchange site to file this on and worked off of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide) which said to go with StackOverflow

Comment: Yeah interesting link. But this really seems to be about screen resolutions, rendering, etc. And that post (and answers) date back to 2009 when the site was *radically* different.